# How to refactor my code to OOP

Tags: c#, oop

Im starting to learn a c# language. Im create a short and easy console aplication which not doing much. Well you can check it. Its about a Footbal(Soccer) game. Im really would like to refactor that code to OOP using classes and method but Im not sure where to start. In my app you can choose one from two teams and then randomly check the results. But I wolud like to add option that you can choose from 1 to much more teams. Well to be honest for the beginning maybe just 4 teams. I know I need to use classes for that insetad of writing the same blocks of code. Its just still hard for me to understand OOP. And if someone can recaftor my code in the simplest way I hope I will get much more from that. Thanks

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int inputGames = 0;
        string userInput;
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Please select your team: Type '1' for FC Barcelona or '2' for Real Madrid: ");
            userInput = Console.ReadLine();

            if (userInput == "1")
            {
                Console.Write("Your select FC Barcelona. How many games you want to play against Real Madrid?: ");
                inputGames = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                break;
            }
            else if (userInput == "2")
            {
                Console.Write("Your select Real Madrid. How many games you want to play against FC Barcelona?: ");
                inputGames = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("Wrong input! Try Again.");
                continue;
            }
        }



        int game = 0;
        //string clubA = "FC Barcelona";
        //string clubB = "Real Madrid";
        int teamAwins = 0;
        int teamBwins = 0;
        int teamAlose = 0;
        int teamBlose = 0;
        int teamAdraw = 0;
        int teamBdraw = 0;
        int teamApoints = 0;
        int teamBpoints = 0;
        int teamAgoles = 0;
        int teamBgoles = 0;

        while (game < inputGames )
        {

            int teamA = 0;
            int teamB = 0;
            int teamAresult = 0;
            int teamBresult = 0;

            int TeamADefense = 8;
            int TeamAMidfield = 9;
            int TeamAAttack = 10;
            int TeamAMentality = 8;

            int TeamBDefense = 9;
            int TeamBMidfield = 8;
            int TeamBAttack = 9;
            int TeamBMentality = 9;


            Random Num = new Random();
            int RandomTADefense = Num.Next(TeamADefense - 5, TeamADefense + 1);
            int RandomTAMidfield = Num.Next(TeamAMidfield - 5, TeamAMidfield + 1);
            int RandomTAAttack = Num.Next(TeamAAttack - 5, TeamAAttack + 1);
            int RandomTAMentality = Num.Next(TeamAMentality - 5, TeamAMentality + 1);

            int RandomTBDefense = Num.Next(TeamBDefense - 5, TeamBDefense + 1);
            int RandomTBMidfield = Num.Next(TeamBMidfield - 5, TeamBMidfield + 1);
            int RandomTBAttack = Num.Next(TeamBAttack - 5, TeamBAttack + 1);
            int RandomTBMentality = Num.Next(TeamBMentality - 5, TeamBMentality + 1);

            //Console.WriteLine("FC Barcelona - Defense: {0}", RandomTADefense);
            //Console.WriteLine("FC Barcelona - Midfield: {0}", RandomTAMidfield);
            //Console.WriteLine("FC Barcelona - Attack: {0}", RandomTAAttack);
            //Console.WriteLine("FC Barcelona - Mentality: {0}", RandomTAMentality);
            //Console.WriteLine("Real Madrid - Defense: {0}", RandomTBDefense);
            //Console.WriteLine("Real Madrid - Midfield: {0}", RandomTBMidfield);
            //Console.WriteLine("Real Madrid - Attack: {0}", RandomTBAttack);
            //Console.WriteLine("Real Madrid - Mentality: {0}", RandomTBMentality);


            if (RandomTADefense > RandomTBDefense)
            {
                teamA++;
            }
            else
            {
                teamB++;
            }
            if (RandomTAMidfield > RandomTBMidfield)
            {
                teamA++;
            }

            else
            {
                teamB++;
            }
            if (RandomTAAttack > RandomTBAttack)
            {
                teamA++;
            }

            else
            {
                teamB++;
            }
            if (RandomTAMentality > RandomTBMentality)
            {
                teamA++;
            }

            else
            {
                teamB++;
            }
            Random result = new Random();

            if(teamA > teamB)
            {
                teamAwins++;
                teamBlose++;
                teamApoints += 3;
                if (teamA == 4)
                {
                    int winner = result.Next(4, 7);
                    teamAresult = winner;
                    teamBresult = winner - result.Next(4, winner);
                    teamAgoles += winner;
                    teamBgoles += teamBresult;
                }
                else if (teamA == 3)
                {
                    int winner = result.Next(3, 5);
                    teamAresult = winner;
                    teamBresult = winner - result.Next(2, winner);
                    teamAgoles += winner;
                    teamBgoles += teamBresult;
                }
                else if (teamA == 2)
                {
                    int winner = result.Next(1, 3);
                    teamAresult = winner;
                    teamBresult = winner - result.Next(1, winner);
                    teamAgoles += winner;
                    teamBgoles += teamBresult;
                }
            }else if (teamB > teamA)
            {
                teamBwins++;
                teamAlose++;
                teamBpoints += 3;
                if (teamB == 4)
                {
                    int winner = result.Next(4, 7);
                    teamBresult = winner;
                    teamAresult = winner - result.Next(4, winner);
                    teamBgoles += winner;
                    teamAgoles += teamAresult;
                }
                else if (teamB == 3)
                {
                    int winner = result.Next(3, 5);
                    teamBresult = winner;
                    teamAresult = winner - result.Next(2, winner);
                    teamBgoles += winner;
                    teamAgoles += teamAresult;
                }
                else if (teamB == 2)
                {
                    int winner = result.Next(2, 3);
                    teamBresult = winner;
                    teamAresult = winner - result.Next(1, winner);
                    teamBgoles += winner;
                    teamAgoles += teamAresult;
                }
            }

            else
            {
                teamAdraw++;
                teamBdraw++;
                teamApoints++;
                teamBpoints++;
                int winner = result.Next(2, 5);
                teamAresult = winner - teamA;
                teamBresult = winner - teamB;
                teamAgoles += teamAresult;
                teamBgoles += teamBresult;
            }


            game++;
           // Console.WriteLine("\nFC Barcelona {0} - {1} Real Madrid", teamA, teamB);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}. FC Barcelona {1} - {2} Real Madrid",game, teamAresult , teamBresult);

            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        if (userInput == "1")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("FC Barcelona - Points: {0}, Wins: {1}, Draws: {2}, Losses: {3}, Goles: {4}", teamApoints, teamAwins, teamAdraw, teamAlose, teamAgoles);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Real Madrid - Points: {0}, Wins: {1}, Draws: {2}, Losses: {3}, Goles: {4}", teamBpoints, teamBwins, teamBdraw, teamBlose, teamBgoles);
        }






        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `if someone can recaftor my code in the simplest way` . No this is not a  *code refactoring*, *write a code for me* , *do my homework* or *code translation* site

Comment: In your code, you have a few "common" things that look like they would be good candidates. E.g. you have Team A and Team B, all of which have the same properties. They would be good candidates to convert to a "Team" object, and have some properties/methods to manage them.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a "refactor my code for me" site.

Answer (score 1):

//I can't write complete code for you, but will try to give an overall structure which would be helping for you as it looks like you already know the coding but just looking for the initial help of structuring the code to follow OOPS.

```
//You can have an Enum for team types as


public enum TeamType
{
     Barcelona, RealMadrid  // This can be extended at any point of time
}

//You can create a class as

Class Team{
    //Properties
    public int ID{get; set;}
    public string Name{get; set;}
    public TeamType Type{get; set;}
    public int InputGames{get; set;}

    //Methods
    //write your methods here 
}

// You can write you program here to use these as
class Program
{
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         //Program would be written here
         //If one team is needed, you will create one object of Team class. 
         //Similarily you can create as many number of Team object as many 
         //teams you need
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Still foreign language for me but I will try.